# await until another async function complete

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm new to the Flutter. I'm calling a `async` function to get the data from server.In my code `Navigator.push()` has to be executed after the async `onEdit()` function complete. But for me `Navigator.push()` executed before `onEdit()` completes.

code:

```
    void  onEdit()async {
     value= await getJson();
     print(value);
  }
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(33, 64, 95, 1.0),
        leading: Icon(Icons.chevron_left),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
              onPressed: (){
                onEdit();
                Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new Case(value)) );
              },
              child: Text(
                "Edit",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ))
        ],
      ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call the `onEdit` function with the `await` keyword.

```
Future<void> onEdit() async {
  value = await getJson();
  print(value);
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(33, 64, 95, 1.0),
      leading: Icon(Icons.chevron_left),
      actions: <Widget>[
        FlatButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            await onEdit();
            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new Case(value)) );
          },
          child: Text(
            "Edit",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          )
        )
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```